# why the desturctor called in reverse order?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

In the inheritance why the destructor called in the reverse order as constructor ?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

class Base {
int value ; 
public : 
Base()value{0}{std::cout << "Base Constructor called" << std::endl; }
~Base(){std::cout << "Base Destructor called" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
int d_value ; 
public : 
Derived()d_value{0}{std::cout << "Derived Constructor called" << std::endl; }
~Derived(){std::cout << "Derived Destructor called" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
Derived d ; 
return 0 ; 
}
```

- //Output
- Base Constructor called
- Derived Constructor called
- Derived Destructor called
- Base Destructor called

Comment: Because the language guarantees this (*and* it makes sense! :)) If you google "c++ order of destruction", there is a lot of information.

Comment: This is just defined behavior. Imagine a house: You built it from bottom to top, and you destruct from top to bottom. Doing the latter from bottom to top may cause that the top falls onto your head.

Comment: And another relevant read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241385/why-the-destructor-in-c-de-allocated-memory-in-reverse-order-of-how-they-were

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is as it is defined in C++ standard: the order of destroying things, like member variables, bases, local objects in a scope, is the inverse of creation order.

Would you like your `Derived`'s dtor body to be run when `Base` has already been destroyed and can be used no more?